# Showing special sigh (?) in blank space after compress html code

Tags: html

I have run website http://jobsf.in and http://ibpsbi.in I am using intractive theme on my all websites. If I enable html code compress tool through wp-rocket pluging, after that in the double blank space have fill with special sign (?) in one blank space. Like this-

1.�आपको ऐप के मुख्य इंटरफेस

2.�इसके बाद सेटिंग्स में जाएं,

or
directly to your website or blog.
�
after paragraph chang...

What may be solution of thei problem